# No CMake configuration found

Tags: qt

CMake project configuration failed. No CMake configuration for build type "Debug" found.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5UEa.png)

:-1: error: CMake project configuration failed. No CMake configuration for build type "Debug" found.

Answer (score 0):

This may occur if you specify `set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)` in your CMakeLists.txt, but choosen `Debug` project configuration in Qt Creator's project setting. The solution is to remove that instruction from CMakeLists.txt

Answer (score 0):

For me, this was caused by old project configurations in QtCreator (the `CMakeLists.txt.user.*` files for CMake or `*.pro.user.*` files for qmake).

Closing the project, removing the files, and re-importing the project solved the issue.